# Tailwind classes not getting applied for Astro Layouts

Tags: tailwind-css, astrojs

I am using Astro Tailwind integration, and I am trying to add some tailwind classes to `MainLayout.astro` which resides in `layouts` directory as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="mx-20 mb-20 md:mb-28 xl:container xl:mx-auto">
      <slot />
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

But styles are not getting applied to the `<main>` tag (according to browser dev tools inspection), but styles to the rest of the pages are getting applied.

What I have tried?

- Restarting the dev server

Edit:

tailwind.config.cjs look like below

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,mdx,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}"],
  ...
};
```

Edit 2:

`astro.config.mjs`

```
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";
import react from "@astrojs/react";
import image from "@astrojs/image";

import tailwind from "@astrojs/tailwind";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [
    react(),
    tailwind(),
    image({
      serviceEntryPoint: "@astrojs/image/sharp",
    }),
  ],
});
```

Comment: What does your `tailwind.config.cjs` file look like? Does the `content` setting include a match for your `MainLayout.astro` file?

Comment: @stickyuser yes it does match the layout file, added the content pattern to the post.

Comment: So you can see `<main class="mx-20 mb-20 md:mb-28 xl:container xl:mx-auto">` in the html of the page, but the classes, e.g. `mx-20`, are not in the stylesheet output so don't have any affect on the page style?

Comment: Actually, as I said in the post, there is no classes on `<main>` tag when you inspect it with dev tools.

Comment: Could you show your Astro config file?

Comment: @MarijnKneppers added astro config as requested